# Enabling Oxford Comma and customizing "and" with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to enable the Oxford Comma (for 3 or more authors), as well as replace "and" with "&" in the bibliography and citations. I can do one or the other, but trying to do both doesn't enable the Oxford Comma.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{3people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2 and Bob Smith3},
  title     = {Some Random Thing},
  date      = {1970}
}
@book{2people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2},
  title     = {Some Other Thing},
  date      = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % Make last names come before first names
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{\addspace\&\addspace} % Replace "and" with "&"
\DefineBibliographyExtras{UKenglish}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}} % Enable Oxford Comma

\begin{document}

\parencite{2people}\par\parencite{3people}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Desired output:

> (Smith1 & Smith2 1971)
> (Smith1, Smith2, & Smith3 1970)
>
> **References**
>
> Smith1, J. & Smith2, A. (1971). Some Other Thing.
> Smith1, J., Smith2, A., & Smith3, B. (1970). Some Random Thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look up the original definition of `finalnamedelim` in [`biblatex.def`, ll. 85-87 in v3.14](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L85)

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
```

and modify it to produce "&" instead of "and" as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, uniquename=init, giveninits]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}% Make last names come before first names

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space}
  
\DefineBibliographyExtras{UKenglish}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}} % Enable Oxford Comma

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{3people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2 and Bob Smith3},
  title     = {Some Random Thing},
  date      = {1970},
}
@book{2people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2},
  title     = {Some Other Thing},
  date      = {1971},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{2people}\par\parencite{3people}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Smith1 & Smith2 1971)//(Smith1, Smith2, & Smith3 1970)]

The results in the example are the same as in [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549818/35864), but there are two relevant differences.

1. This answer uses that `finalnamedelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter and uses the interfaces for that. (It is not an error to use `\renewcommand` on a context-sensitive delimiter, but I prefer to use the new interface, since it generalises to other delimiter contexts more naturally.)
2. This solution preserves the use of `\finalandcomma` for the Oxford comma. That means it needs more code than Ulrike's answer, but it is more modular.

The answer also uses `etoolbox`'s `\ifnumgreater` instead of `ifthen`'s `\ifthenelse`, but that is mostly a matter of taste (and the `biblatex` code base is not terribly consistent here: `biblatex.def` does not use `\ifthenelse`, but some `.cbx` and `.bbx` files do).

Answer (score 1):

You can test the listcount:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,giveninits]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{3people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2 and Bob Smith3},
  title     = {Some Random Thing},
  date      = {1970}
}
@book{2people,
  author    = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2},
  title     = {Some Other Thing},
  date      = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % Make last names come before first names
% Replace "and" with "&", and add Oxford Comma
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>2}{\addcomma}{}\addspace\&\addspace}

\begin{document}

\parencite{2people}\par\parencite{3people}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]